# Why does git ignore my edits to COMMIT_EDITMSG?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

```
$ git config --global core.editor
code --wait
```

When I run `git commit --amend`, a new tab is opened in VSCode named `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but the command doesn't wait for me to edit and close the tab—the command completes and I get a new prompt in the terminal. When I edit the commit message, save, and close, and then do `git log`, the message hasn't changed.

Comment: Can it be that the setting `git.useEditorAsCommitInput` is switched on?

Comment: It is on. However, when I uncheck it, I get the same behavior.